# C++ - Why does my program close after calling a function again?

Tags: c++

I'm new to C++ and can't figure out what's going on here...

Basically I have a function with a bunch of Log("...") statements (text-based adventure)
and then I want to basically create a try-catch block to see if the user tries to print anything that isn't 1 or 2 as those are the only 2 choices. I noticed when you input strings into the console it converts it to 0 so basically my code is-

```
void myfunciton()
{
    top:

    Log("Choose...");
    Log("(1) ...");
    Log("(2) ...");

    std::cout << std::string(11, '\n') << std:endl;

    std::cout << "Enter a number: ";
    std::cin >> userchoice; // Userchoice is a global variable defined above and set to 100.

    if (userchoice == 0) {
    userchoice = 100;
    goto top;
}
```

Instead of the line goto top; I also tried just calling myFunction(); but it gives me the same outcome... The code runs again and I see my story, but I can't enter another number. It prints out the line "Enter a number: " inside my console, but than immediately prints "exited with code 0 press any key to close..."

I just don't understand why it isn't letting me input another number again. Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: Do yourself a favor and pretend that `goto` does not exist.  There are use cases for it, but a loop is not one of them.  Once you have mastered the basics of C++, you can revisit `goto` and see where it actually should be used.

Comment: You have an endless loop.  You should read up on the `return`, and `break` statements.

Comment: There is a syntax error:  no closing brace for the `if` statement.

Comment: "*I want to basically create a try-catch block to see if the user tries to print anything that isn't 1 or 2 as those are the only 2 choices*" - `operator>>` does not throw an exception on bad input unless you enable that behavior beforehand by calling the `std::istream`'s [`exceptions()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/exceptions) method. Even then, that will only throw if input can't be converted to the *type* being read, but will not throw when reading *incorrect values* of that type. You have to manage that validation yourself separately.

Comment: "*I noticed when you input strings into the console it converts it to 0*" - that behavior was not standardized until C++11.  The *correct* thing to do is check the state of the `std::istream` after `operator>>` returns, that will tell you if the read was successful or not, eg `if (std::cin >> userchoice) { /* validate userchoice as needed... */ } else { /* error, do something else... */ }`

Answer (score 0):

Because the numerical extractor leaves non-digits behind in the input buffer.
Try this:

`std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');`

and avoid using goto-s.

Also you can use:`while (std::cin >> x)` (x is for your input) for better flow of code.